# python - Which is the better way to enable/disable logging?

Tags: python, logging

Which is better way to enable/disable logging?

1) Changing log levels,

```
logging.disable(logging.CRITICAL)
```

2)

```
log = None
```

And logging messages this way,

```
if log:
    log.info("log message")
```

So that we can avoid unnecessary string constructions in case of logging disabled...

Comment: Have you tried benchmarking your two options?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1 is best, ideally via a configuration file or command line argument (--quiet)

2 will just clutter up your code

If you want to avoid expensive string construction (this is probably worthwhile about 0.001% of the time in my experience), use:

```
if logger.isEnabledFor(logging.DEBUG):
    logger.debug("Message with %s, %s", expensive_func1(),
                                        expensive_func2())
```

http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#optimization

Comment: This assumes you have the current or root logger in `logger`. If you just use `logging.debug(...)` you need to check as follows: `if logging.getLogger().isEnabledFor(logging.DEBUG): ...`.